# regular expression all 0's and 1's 4 characters or less using only | () * and concat

Tags: regex, regular-language

Without using "extended" regex operators such as {}, ?, ^, and +, using **only** | () * and concat, how can a regular expression find all strings of length four or less if the only characters in the language are 0 and 1?

the regular expression should match:

0 or 1

10 or 01

111 or 110 or other length 3 strings

0011 or 0010 or other length 4 strings

but not 01101 or any string 5 or longer.

I am able to draw a deterministic finite state automata for the language, but have been unsuccessful in determining a regular expression.

My guess would be it cannot use the * and be something similar to (0|1)(0|1)(0|1)(0|1) but I don't have a way of making the last three sets of parentheses optional.

edit: this is for a homework problem

Comment: Hint: {Strings of length 1} | {Strings of length 2} | {Strings of length 3} | {Strings of length 4}.

Comment: It is homework - forgot to mention this in the OP

Comment: Dukeling, good hint - I've got it figured out now

Answer (score 1):

This could easily be achieved by this regex: `^[01]{1,4}$`. I cannot see why would one not want to use `{}` in regex.

`[01]` would allow one of these two digits, and `{1,4}` states that there could be only 1 to 4 zero or ones. `^` and `$` indicate the start and end of the string.

If you still do not want to use `{}`, you could go for this:

```
^(([01][01][01][01])|([01][01][01])|([01][01])|([01]))$
```

If you are not allowed you use `[]` as well, this regex could be used instead.

```
^(((0|1)(0|1)(0|1)(0|1))|((0|1)(0|1)(0|1))|((0|1)(0|1))|((0|1)))$
```

Comment: Unfortunately, {} are not allowed in the regex - and I find it odd as well.

Comment: i have updated my answer, hope it helps.

Comment: My answer was along these lines, but I could not use [] either.

Comment: answer updated again to match your needs

Comment: @user1569114: Normal `[character]` class (not the negated one) in "practical" regular expression, is equivalent to `(c|h|a|r|a|c|t|e|r)` in theoretical regular expression syntax.

Answer (score 0):

(0|1)|(00|01|10|11)|(000|001|010|011|100|101|110|111)|(0000|0001|0010|0011|0100|0101|0110|0111|1000|1001|1010|1011|1100|1101|1110|1111)

Comment: whats the use of regex if you are matching each and every possible combination. you could have compare the exact strings instead. try making use of regex in a proper manner.

Comment: I've had to derive other regular expressions in this same homework using the same restrictions (only | * () and concat) where it wasn't necessary to type out every single combination in this manner. Such as, create all non-empty substrings in the language of 0s and 1s not containing the substring 011. In this case, the regular expression is short (four *s, four numbers, two pipes and four parentheses). But as for this particular one, I can't use $ or ^ either.